# Custom autocomplete doesn't go outside the div

Tags: css, dropdown

I checked a lot of questions on SO and a lot of them solves the opposite of what I want, and the others suggest to use `absolute` and `relative`, what I've tried, up to no avail.

I have a custom dropdown menu I made inspired by this: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_autocomplete.asp

I use this dropdown in an overlay, but actually my list doesn't go outside the div if I have a lot of elements.

Here is what I want to do:

[image]

- the dropdown has the same width than the input;
- when there are too many items, there is a scroll bar;
- when the dropdown is too big it goes outside the div.

Here is what I did so far:

```css
.content {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  height: 85%;
}

.tool {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.overlay {
  z-index: 200;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.fondOverlay {
  background-color: rgba(10, 10, 10, 0.8);
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 199;
}

.contenuFormulaireOverlay {
  width: 40%;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-height: 30%;
  max-height: 60%;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  z-index: 201;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.contenuFormulaireOverlay > div {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.contenuFormulaireOverlay > div > div {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 5px;
}

.autocomplete * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.autocomplete {
  position: relative;
  /* display: inline-block; */
  overflow: visible;
  width: 90%;
}
input {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 1em;
}
input[type=text] {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100%;
}
.autocomplete-items {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-top: none;
  z-index: 99;
  /*position the autocomplete items to be the same width as the container:*/
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: left;
}
.autocomplete-items div {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
}
.autocomplete-items div:hover {
  /*when hovering an item:*/
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
}
.autocomplete-active {
  /*when navigating through the items using the arrow keys:*/
  background-color: DodgerBlue !important;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
   <div class="tool">
      <header>
         <h1>TITLE</h1>
      </header>
      <div class="realContent">
        THE CONTENT
      </div>
   </div>
   <!--v-if-->
   <div class="overlay">
      <div class="fondOverlay"></div>
      <div class="contenuFormulaireOverlay">
         <div>
            <div>
               <label>POC:</label>
               <div class="autocomplete">
                  <input type="text" placeholder="Write something...">
                  <div class="autocomplete-items">
                     <div>
                        <span>  123456 - AAA  </span>
                     </div>
                     <div>
                        <span >  100000 - BBB </span>
                     </div>
                     <div>
                        <span>  CCC</span>
                     </div>
                     <div>
                        <span>  DDD</span>
                     </div>
                     <div>
                        <span>  EEE</span>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <span class="button"> Add </span>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

What I would like is for the dropdown to go outside the div, in front of everything. I tried `z-index` but it doesn't work either...

Answer (score 1):

Hope i understand what you ask..
I added
`.autocomplete-items { width: 100%; position: relative; }`
to your last snippet...

```css
.content {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  height: 85%;
}

.tool {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.overlay {
  z-index: 200;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.fondOverlay {
  background-color: rgba(10, 10, 10, 0.8);
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 199;
}

.contenuFormulaireOverlay {
  width: 80%;
  /*overflow: hidden;*/
  min-height: 30%;
  max-height: 60%;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  z-index: 201;
  /*display: flex;*/
  font-size: 1.2em;
  /*flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;*/

  position: absolute;
}

.contenuFormulaireOverlay > div {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.contenuFormulaireOverlay > div > div {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 5px;
}

.autocomplete * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.autocomplete {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 250px;
  width: 90%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 55px;
  left: 5%;
}
input {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 1em;
}
input[type=text] {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100%;
}
.autocomplete-items {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-top: none;
  z-index: 99;
  text-align: left;
}
.autocomplete-items div {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
  
}
.autocomplete-items div:hover {
  /*when hovering an item:*/
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
}
.autocomplete-active {
  /*when navigating through the items using the arrow keys:*/
  background-color: DodgerBlue !important;
  color: #ffffff;
}
/* the add button on the bottom of the list get lost so i change it position and style it for demonstarion */
.button {position: absolute; top: 20px; right: 20px; cursor: pointer}
```

```html
<div class="content">
   <div class="tool">
      <header>
         <h1>TITLE</h1>
      </header>
      <div class="realContent">
        THE CONTENT
      </div>
   </div>
   <!--v-if-->
   <div class="overlay">
      <div class="fondOverlay"></div>
      <div class="contenuFormulaireOverlay">
         <div>
            <div>
               <label>POC:</label>
               <div class="autocomplete">
                  <input type="text" placeholder="Write something...">
                  <div class="autocomplete-items">
                     <div>
                        <span>  123456 - AAA  </span>
                     </div>
                     <div>
                        <span >  100000 - BBB </span>
                     </div>
                     <div>
                        <span>  CCC</span>
                     </div>
                     <div>
                        <span>  DDD</span>
                     </div>
                     <div>
                        <span>  EEE</span>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>            
         </div>
         <span class="button"> Add </span>
      </div>
      
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. Actually, I'd like the dropdown to go outside the light grey container. You can look at my answer, it gives a correct result but I feel it's not the perfect way to do it...

Comment: @djcaesar9114 can you add a picture of the desired design?

Comment: Hello, I just did :)

Comment: @djcaesar9114 check my edit

Comment: It's almost that, thank you: I'd like the "input" to still be in the flow between "POC" and"Add". Because this component is a form to fill, the user has to see the fields in the order they appear.

Comment: @djcaesar9114 do you mean change `.autocomplete {top: 55px}` etc (like id did in my edit right now) ?? play with that to get what you desire.

Answer (score 0):

For the moment I managed to have this but I'm still not fully satisfied. I don't know why but it doesn't feel like it's the good answer:

```css
.content {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  height: 85%;
}

.tool {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.overlay {
  z-index: 200;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.fondOverlay {
  background-color: rgba(10, 10, 10, 0.8);
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 199;
}

.contenuFormulaireOverlay {
  width: 40%;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-height: 30%;
  max-height: 60%;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  z-index: 201;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.contenuFormulaireOverlay > div {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.contenuFormulaireOverlay > div > div {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 5px;
}

.autocomplete * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.autocomplete {
  overflow: visible;
  width: 90%;
}
input {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 1em;
}
input[type=text] {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100%;
}
.autocomplete-items {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-top: none;
  z-index: 99;
  text-align: left;
}
.autocomplete-items div {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
}
.autocomplete-items div:hover {
  /*when hovering an item:*/
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
}
.autocomplete-active {
  /*when navigating through the items using the arrow keys:*/
  background-color: DodgerBlue !important;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
   <div class="tool">
      <header>
         <h1>TITLE</h1>
      </header>
      <div class="realContent">
        THE CONTENT
      </div>
   </div>
   <!--v-if-->
   <div class="overlay">
      <div class="fondOverlay"></div>
      <div class="contenuFormulaireOverlay">
         <div>
            <div>
               <label>POC:</label>
               <div class="autocomplete">
                  <input type="text" placeholder="Write something...">
                  <div class="autocomplete-items">
                     <div>
                        <span>  123456 - AAA  </span>
                     </div>
                     <div>
                        <span >  100000 - BBB </span>
                     </div>
                     <div>
                        <span>  CCC</span>
                     </div>
                     <div>
                        <span>  DDD</span>
                     </div>
                     <div>
                        <span>  EEE</span>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <span class="button"> Add </span>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```